# The dns server developed by golang cannot be resolved

Tags: go, dns

I am trying to use golang to write a custom dns server.
At present, nslookup and dig have parsed the corresponding requests normally,
but curl, wget, ping and the like cannot respond to dns requests

Haven't tried Windows and Linux yet

Currently using dnsmasq, but I still want to write my own dns server, because I don't want to make the program too big

system: macos 13
go: go1.20.1

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/miekg/dns"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

var IPS = map[string]string{
    "nginx.docker.shared": "192.168.0.99",
}

func main() {
    dns.HandleFunc("docker.shared.", func(w dns.ResponseWriter, m *dns.Msg) {
        r := new(dns.Msg)
        r.SetReply(m)
        r.Compress = true
        r.Authoritative = true
        r.RecursionAvailable = true
        IPAddress := "NULL"
        Domain := strings.TrimRight(r.Question[0].Name, ".")

        defer func(w dns.ResponseWriter, msg *dns.Msg) {
            log.Infof("Query: [%v ? %s --> %v]\n", w.RemoteAddr(), Domain, IPAddress)
            err := w.WriteMsg(msg)
            if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Error writing response: %v", err)
                return
            }
        }(w, r)

        // not resolve
        if r.Question[0].Qtype != dns.TypeA {
            r.Rcode = dns.RcodeNotImplemented
            return
        }

        if addr := IPS[Domain]; addr != "" {
            IPAddress = addr
            r.Answer = append(r.Answer, &dns.A{
                Hdr: dns.RR_Header{
                    Name:   m.Question[0].Name,
                    Rrtype: dns.TypeA,
                    Class:  dns.ClassINET,
                    Ttl:    uint32(86400),
                },
                A: net.ParseIP(IPAddress).To4(),
            })
        }

        if len(r.Answer) == 0 {
            r.Rcode = dns.RcodeNameError
        }
    })
    // start server
    udpServer := &dns.Server{Addr: ":53", Net: "udp"}
    log.Printf("Starting at %v\n", udpServer.Addr)
    if err := udpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to setup the udp server: %s\n", err.Error())
    }

    defer func(udpServer *dns.Server) {
        err := udpServer.Shutdown()
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf("Failed to shutdown the udp server: %s\n", err.Error())
            return
        }
    }(udpServer)
}
```

[image: system dns setting]

[image: dns response]

tks，very much

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: As you can see from your logs - your DNS server does not even gets queried for curl, wget or ping. So this is not a problem of your code, and thus not a programming problem. It is instead an issue of how DNS lookup works on MacOS, and therefore more a topic at [apple.se]. See [DNS Resolution Fails for ping and curl, but not dig](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251678/dns-resolution-fails-for-ping-and-curl-but-not-dig) over there.

Comment: The current problem is temporarily resolved, thanks to [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) and [dushixiang](https://github.com/dushixiang) for their help